# Questions regarding a PHP SQL booking system

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am building a reservation system for a holiday complex (similar to hotel but instead of rooms there are a variety of apartments).  In order to avoid double bookings, the system needs to check if a particular apartment is booked during the date range chosen by the potential guests, and then proceed if there are no problems or inform them to change dates or apartment if dates chosen are part of a taken group of dates.  I am trying to figure out how to check if the dates selected fall in a previously selected date range.
As an example: if the date range 08/09/2015 - 08/12/2015 is already booked, and then the date range 08/10/2015 - 08/15/2015 gets selected - the guest gets the notification to select new dates or a different apartment, else if the date range chosen is 08/15/2015 - 08/20/2015 the form is processed.

My booking system so far:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
if (isset($_POST['proceedtopaypal'])){
    $apartment = $_POST['apartment'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $pax = $_POST['pax'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
    $day_from = $_POST['day_from'];
    $month_from = $_POST['month_from'];
    $year_from = $_POST['year_from'];
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = $_POST['day_to'];
    $month_to = $_POST['month_to'];
    $year_to = $_POST['year_to'];
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) -   strtotime($booking_from));       
    $days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

    printf("%d nights\n", $days);
    $validdate = false;
    $buttonpressed = false;
    $nodate='<p>date does not exist.</p>\n';
    $noinfo='<p>please fill in the missing information.</p>\n';
    $baddate='<p>selected dates is already booked.</p>\n';
    $thankyou='<p>thank you for your reservation.<br>a confirmation     email will be sent shortly</p>\n';
      $window = '';

    function IsInjected($str)
    { 
       $injections = array('(\n+)',
                   '(\r+)',
                   '(\t+)',
                   '(%0A+)',
                   '(%0D+)',
                   '(%08+)',
                   '(%09+)'
                   );
       $inject = join('|', $injections);
      $inject = "/$inject/i";
      if(preg_match($inject,$str))
        {
        return true;
      }
      else
        {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if ($booking_from == (($day_from == "31") && ($month_from == "2"))  || (($day_from == "31") && ($month_from == "4")) || (($day_from == "31") && ($month_from == "6")) || (($day_from == "31") && ($month_from == "9")) || (($day_from == "31") && ($month_from == "11")) || (($day_from == "30") && ($month_from == "2")) || (($day_from == "29") && ($month_from == "2") &&  ($year_from %4 != 0))   ) {
        //$window=$nodate; 
        echo "Date does not exist";
        $validdate = true;
    } 
     else if ($booking_to == (($day_to == "31") && ($month_to == "2"))     || (($day_to == "31") && ($month_to == "4")) || (($day_to == "31") && ($month_to == "6")) || (($day_to == "31") && ($month_to == "9")) || (($day_to == "31") && ($month_to == "11")) || (($day_to == "30") && ($month_to == "2")) || (($day_to == "29") && ($month_to == "2") && ($year_to %4 != 0))   ) {
        //$window=$nodate; 
        echo "Date does not exist";
        $validdate = true;
    } 
    else if  (($name == "Name") || ($surname == "surname") || ($email == "Email") || ($address == "Address")) {
        //$window=$noinfo;
        echo "Missing information";
    }
    else if (IsInjected($email)) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Email")';
        echo '</script>';
    }

    else if ($validdate == false) {
        $final = true;
        include 'connect.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE ($booking_from  BETWEEN date_from AND date_to) OR ($booking_to BETWEEN date_from AND date_to)";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($apartment == $row['apartmentID']  && $booking_from >= $row['date_from'] && $booking_to <= $row['date_to']){
                //$window=$badtime;
                echo "Apartment is taken";
                $final = false;
            }
            else {
                echo "All OK";
            } 
        }
    }
}

}
```

The SQL table has this setup:

```
> BookingID - int
> ApartmentID - int
> ClientID - int
> date_from - date (Format: yyyy-mm-dd)
> date_to - date  (Format: yyyy-mm-dd)
> no of nights - int (achieved by subtracting date_from from date_to)
> pax - int (number of people)
> paid - int
```

The visible code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="bookstay">
                    <input type="hidden" name="apartment" value="<?php get_apartment_text("SELECT apartmentID from apartment_details WHERE apartmentID = ?", "apartmentID"); ?>"/>
                    <input name='name' class="short-input" type="text" value="Name" onFocus="this.value = ''" />
                    <input  name= 'surname' class="short-input" type="text" value="surname" onFocus="this.value = ''" />
                    <input  name='email' class="long-input" type="text" value="Email" onFocus="this.value = ''"  />
                    <input name='address' class="long-input" type="text" value="Address" onFocus="this.value = ''" />
                    <input name='mobile'  class="short-input" type="text" value="mobile" onFocus="this.value = ''"  />
                    <div class="select" id="peopletostay">
                        <select name="pax" class="short-input">
                            <option value="0">people to stay</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dateofarrival">
                    date of arrival<br>                 
                    <?php include 'date-from.php'; ?>
                   </div>
                     <div id="dateofdeparture">
                    date of departure<br>                 
                    <?php include 'date-to.php'; ?>
                   </div>
                   <textarea name='remarks'>Extra Remarks</textarea>
                   </div>
                  <button type='submit' name='proceedtopaypal'>
                  </form>
```

Comment: You should take this question to codereview

Comment: I've built a hotel reservation system, and it gets quite complicated if you want it done right. I would try to help you, but your question is way to vague, unfortunately. Try narrowing it down if you can.

Comment: Also, most likely whatever you are doing with `IsInjected()` is already coded into PHP (and most likely better than what you have done). And check out http://php.net/checkdate instead of your home brew date checker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having everything in your `booking` table, I would make the following separate tables:

- `bookings` - Note, it's pretty standard to use plural instead of singular, so if it's not too much work, I would change this. You can get rid of `apartmentId` and `number_of_nights` from this. The first one will be handled by the `room_nights` table (below) and the second one is pretty meaningless to store in the DB since it can be calculated quite easily.
- `apartments` - I assume this is already done. Just add the information about each apartment here, such as number of rooms, description, etc.
- `clients` - I also assume this is done. Add any information about the client here.
- `room_nights` - This keeps track of the full apartments on any given night. You will add one entry for every single night an apartment is full. This should contain the `date`, `booking_id` and `apartment_id` only.
- `blocked_rooms` (optional) - This would work the same as `room_nights`, however it allows you to keep track of any dates you want to prevent bookings without having an actual booking (for example, for maintenance).

Then to query if an apartment is full for any given night, you would do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM room_nights
WHERE date >= :check_in 
AND date < :check_out
AND apartment_id = ?
```

If you also want to use `blocked_rooms` you could just do the same as above or use a `UNION` to do it all in one query.

You could then easily output this to a calendar table with apartments on the y-axis and dates on the x-axis to visualize the booked/empty/blocked apartments. This is what I have done in my program:

[image]

Now if you would like to allow the apartments to have dynamic rates, this is the table structure that I have used:

### `rates` table:

This is where you put the name for the rate as well as several restrictions.

```
CREATE TABLE `rates` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `rate_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `days_advance_min` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `days_advance_max` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `booking_date_start` datetime NOT NULL,
 `booking_date_end` datetime NOT NULL,
 `booking_date_end_unlimited` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `min_people` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `max_people` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `rate_name` (`rate_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The `days_advance_*` columns are the min/max number of days in advanced the rate is available. The `booking_date_*` columns are to determine when this rate is available to be booked. So if you only want it to be available starting on a certain date, you put that there. The `booking_date_end_unlimited` is just to keep track if there is no final booking date. You may not want to use `BIT(1)` for that column because it is harder to work with.

### `rates_apartments`

A relational table to link the rate to an apartment ID

### `rate_dates`

This is where the actual "rate" goes in. You have one for every day the rate is available. There is no need for a start/end date anywhere because any dates available you will be adding a rate here:

```
CREATE TABLE `rate_dates` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `rate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `single` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `second_adult` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `third_adult` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `fourth_adult` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `extra_adult` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `extra_child` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `min_nights` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `max_nights` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `rate_id` (`rate_id`,`date`),
 UNIQUE KEY `rate_id_3` (`rate_id`,`date`),
 KEY `rate_id_2` (`rate_id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 CONSTRAINT `rate_dates_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rate_id`) REFERENCES `rates` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3219 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I think everything here should be self-explanatory. The rate is calculated by adding the `single + second_adult + third_adult` etc, depending on the number of people. If you don't want to vary the rate depending on the number of people, just set a single "rate" value and you could get rid of the min/max people in the `rates` table as well.

Finally, this is the query I use to actually get the rates:

```
// Get available rates for each night
$placeholders = substr(str_repeat('?,', count($dates_stayed)), 0, -1);

$query = "
    SELECT
        r.id as rate_id,
        rrt.room_type_id,
        date,
        single,
        second_adult,
        third_adult,
        fourth_adult,
        extra_adult,
        extra_child,
        r.min_people as rates_min_people,
        r.max_people as rates_max_people,
        crt.min_people as crt_min_people,
        crt.max_people as crt_max_people
    FROM rate_dates rd
    LEFT JOIN rates r
        ON rd.rate_id = r.id
    LEFT JOIN rates_room_types rrt
        ON r.id = rrt.rate_id
    LEFT JOIN config_room_types crt
        ON rrt.room_type_id = crt.id
    WHERE
        rd.date IN ( $placeholders )
        AND booking_date_start <= NOW()
        AND (
            booking_date_end >= NOW()
            OR booking_date_end_unlimited = b'1'
        )
        AND DATEDIFF(?, NOW()) >= days_advance_min
        AND (
            days_advance_max = -1
            OR DATEDIFF(?, NOW()) <= days_advance_max
        )
        AND min_nights <= ?
        AND min_nights <= ?
        AND (
            max_nights >= ?
            OR max_nights = -1
        )
    HAVING
        ? >= rates_min_people
        AND ? <= rates_max_people
        AND ? >= crt_min_people
        AND ? <= crt_max_people";

$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
```

The `config_room_types` table would be similar to your `apartments` table in that you can limit the min/max people both at the rate level and at the room level.

Comment: Let me know you are interested in having dynamic rates and I'll update with what I've done to achieve that as well.

Comment: That would be awesome if you can help me with the rates as well :)

Comment: The program I've developed is literally something I've been working on for about 8 years (off and on), but it currently is around 45000 lines of code not even including libraries. It seemed simple at first, but it kept getting more and more complicated as I added more features to it. So if this is the case with you, you may be further ahead just to get some sort of property management software / booking engine already built. Good luck with this.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help :).  The rates would be much simple since I'm using a general rate per apartment per night, irrelevant on the number of people.

Comment: @Christa Feel free to accept this answer and/or upvote it if it answers your question.

Comment: Hi ... was checking the answer and have a couple of small questions - would check_in and check_out be equal to booking_from and booking_to?  In  this SELECT COUNT(*) FROM room_nights
WHERE date >= :check_in 
AND date < :check_out
AND apartment_id = ?

Comment: @Christa check_in is the day they enter, check_out is the day they leave.

Comment: Aaa ok thanks - small question regarding that - why is it that when I check for a date which exists in phpmyadmin I get 0, even though it does? For example: SELECT COUNT(*) as booked FROM room_nights WHERE dates=2015-08-16  gives me 0, when it should give me 1.

Comment: @Christa I have no idea. Try breaking the query apart by commenting out the things in the `WHERE` part until you figure out which one(s) are preventing it from being included.

Comment: Figured that out needed to write it as SELECT COUNT(*) as booked WHERE dates='2015-088-19'